# Why do we explore?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, motivation, evolution, evolutionary-psychology

I'm keep trying to list some of strong motivations to explain our "inner curiosity". But, the subject and this question are very broad, therefore I will give you some context.

1. So, why do we explore? The first class of answers, in my point of view, lies on our physiological necessities.  Our bodies need energy (food...) in order to keep functioning, therefore all the expanse of humankind does have at least a reason: a search for more energy. Hence, our curiosity trais could have a strong genesis in thise matter. Also, if we can "store energy" for a later usage, therefore, in some sense we are optimizing our life; for instance, if we store food, we won't need to stress our bodies to go out and hunt a predator for its meat. In this latter scenario, we will always exaust the resources of the site, then we will need to "explore other lands" sooner or later. Now, up to this stage, humans are social beings, and from our history it is clear that we developed a sense of community. We create all sorts of social structures: tribes, countries, families, etc...
   Well, this social structure paradigm, in principle introduces a well optmized life, since we are together and therefore we can overcome many obstacles in order to survive. Still, many of us keep going out to explore, without any sort of clear physiological necessity

The other class of answers, maybe could lie on the evolution of the human as a social being. Together we are stronger, and we can hunt and store energy with efficiency. The sense of community seems to matter deeply in our pysche as well. In this regard I would like to ask:

> The fear of being "alone" can be a motivation, as stronger as 1., to explaing our sense of curiosity and "need" for exploration? *In other words, which biological traits can explain the feeling of "I need to know what is out there"?*

(Please, try to abstract the usage of the words "hunt" and "food")